# woocommerce: when adding or removing items to cart , it takes cart a few seconds to read changes?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have the most simple cart page . `[woocommerce_cart]` that is it.

when I add products to pages and `view cart` it shows the cart empty , afew refreshes (after afew seconds) the cart populates .

when I remove products from cart it stays the same , again a few refreshes and after a few seconds the item(s) is removed ?

Comment: That doesnt sound right. Have you tried the same with a default theme? Mayve you can try the official storefront theme for testing. Have a look at the woocommerce status page, does it state anything in red?

Comment: yes , even tried a whole different theme.

Comment: yeah , php version and soup client but those are not the issue , if I have time later I will test plugins with the official theme .

Answer (score 0):

problem was occurring due to a `footnotes` plugin , when deactivated the problem is solved ,

I tried a couple more `footnotes` plugins same issue re-occur .

hope that helps .